# How can I create a hibernate collection that will be re-read every time I request it?

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration, caching

I have an entity that has a state table associated with it.  The state table is managed by another process, and contains a list of objects that my business logic must process.  I would like to get a new snapshot of the state table each time I reload the entity.  How can I ensure that no part of Hibernate or its support libraries *ever* caches any of the values of this table?  Basically, I want to get a new view of the collection *every* time I call getMyStateValues ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the point of Hibernate is to prevent that from happening and return a consistent view of an entity's state in the scope of a given transaction. So either reload the whole entity, in different transactions every time. Or, if you need to reload the state table during a business transaction, load only the state table by the parent entity's id in a separate Hibernate session.

Comment: Can I take that to mean that if I commit the transaction in progress, my next read of the collection will contain new values?

Comment: I use Spring's transaction management, so I'm not sure if committing the transaction works or if you should create a new Session off the top of my head. It should clear the first-level cache however.

The second-level cache might still kick in if you're using one though. The default should be not to use one.

This should be easy enough to verify with a test app and a SQL console open on the same DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method in your entity that queries the database and return the collection. getXYXReload(). It´s not a very nice design decision, thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hibernate's [CacheMode](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/class-use/CacheMode.html).  It allows you to instruct a hibernate session on how to interact with the cache.  You can get access to the underlying session with:

```
@PersistenceContext EntityManager manager;
...
org.hibernate.Session session = (Session)manager.getDelegate();
```

Unfortunately, this technique applies to the whole session, and not specifically to an entity.